# How do voting rules work in elections?

Tags: support, voting, election, moderator-primaries

How do voting rules work in elections; are they like the voting rules for questions and answers? Do downvotes in elections cost 2 rep for the candidate and 1 for the voter? Does the vote get locked in five minutes and require the candidate’s nomination to be able to change the vote?

To be clear, I’m asking about the Primary phase of an election where the voting controls look just like those of questions and answers (i.e., up and down arrows).

Answer (score 6):

> How do voting rules work in elections; are they like the voting rules for questions and answers? Do downvotes in elections cost 2 rep for the candidate and 1 for the voter?

No, there are no rep changes associated to nominating yourself or voting in an election.

> Does the vote get locked in five minutes and require the candidate’s nomination to be able to change the vote?

No, it doesn't get locked.

When you cast your third vote in the election phase, the tooltip says:

> You have cast your third vote, thanks for voting!
>
> You can still change your votes until the election ends.

Comment: *> No, it doesn't get locked. When you cast your third vote in the election phase, the tooltip says…*   Yes, I know that, but the election phase has a special voting mechanism. I’m asking about the nomination and primary phases which use the normal Q/A voting controls.

Comment: The same is true for the primary phase, but I can't test/quote the details it right now. You can't vote at all in the nomination phase.

Comment: *> You can't vote at all in the nomination phase.*   Strange; I could have sworn I voting controls in the Nomination phase. Maybe I mixed up Nomination’s comment votes and Primary’s voting controls.

Comment: @Synetech you mean primaries, not nomination

Comment: @Sathya, huh? I said the nomination phase allows votes on comments and the primaries phase has normal voting controls like those in questions and answers.

Comment: @Synetech exactly, nomination phase doesn't have voting, as others mentioned. (ed: nev mind, I misread)

Comment: @Sathya, ah I see; I forgot to remove “nomination” from the question.